# Create summary of data in specified format

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, summary

I have an SQL query which produces the following table:

```
+----------------------+-------+------+------+-----+------+
|       PAYCODE        | HOURS | COST | FROM | TO  | ROLE |
+----------------------+-------+------+------+-----+------+
| EU All Paid Time     |     5 | 66.5 |  583 | 471 | ASSC |
| DE Basic P           |     5 | 66.5 |  583 | 471 | ASSC |
| EU All Hours Average |     4 | 53.2 |  583 | 470 | ASSC |
| EU All Hours Average |     5 | 66.5 |  583 | 471 | ASSC |
| EU All Worked TIme   |     5 | 66.5 |  583 | 471 | ASSC |
| DE Basic P           |     4 | 53.2 |  583 | 470 | ASSC |
| EU All Paid Time     |     4 | 53.2 |  583 | 470 | ASSC |
| EU All Regular       |     4 | 53.2 |  583 | 470 | ASSC |
| EU All Regular       |     5 | 66.5 |  583 | 471 | ASSC |
| EU All Worked TIme   |     4 | 53.2 |  583 | 470 | ASSC |
+----------------------+-------+------+------+-----+------+
```

I want to change the way it looks so that I have the From, To and Role columns as-is on the left, then the paycode names across the column headers with hours underneath, then another set of columns with paycode names across the column headers with costs underneath

How can this be done? I managed to do separate tables of hours/costs using PIVOT, but want the combined view I describe instead.

IT's worth noting that the paycode list will vary depending on what ones are earnt so I don't want to fix the names using a standard pivot

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: If you don't have a fixed list of `paycode`s, then you will need dynamic SQL, which is much more complicated (and vendor specific).

Comment: Updated original post - SQL-server and formatted table

Comment: 1. If you don't want to fix your paycode then you need to use dynamic pivot. There are examples on the internet on how to do it but it is "ugly". 2. To combine your query you can use a simple `inner join` (you will need to create a common key between two tables). To do the same with dynamic pivot will result in exceptionally ugly (and unreadable) sql code. 3. You mention you want this in a view. This will entail having a view return variable number of columns. What is the use case for this? I suggest that you delegate the task of complex pivoting to reporting software.

Comment: We do not currently have the time to write an RDL report to do this for us. We have been given a format to give the information in which is the goal of this query. I have managed 2 separate dynamic pivots which give me a table with hours and a table with costs, but I now need to merge the two to have hours next to costs